# what would be the sequence of script tag while using .js files of coredova and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
<!-- Libraries JS files Start-->
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.mobile/custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/libs/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/libs/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/libs/googleCharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>
```

When I use this it does not show me graphs and gives datatable Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `custom-scripting.js` of the jQuery mobile need the core script first, so change the order to:

```
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/custom-scripting.js"></script>
```

Comment: In that custom-scripting.js i put the mobile init function for no transition if i change sequence as you said it show me the fading effect which i don't want in my application anyway my problem is with d graph library thanks shadow-wizard

Comment: Sorry no slight idea what you mean.